# Saving and Re-instating Jquery draggable and droppable elements

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have a div block and, within that 2 tables, one of which has a number of draggable elements (table rows) and another of which has a number of droppable zones, each zone of which is a table in its own right.

I want to be able to save the state of this div block as work in progress and then reload it and continue at some later time.

I can quite easily save the div to a backend database using ajax and I can reload it, again using ajax, plus assigning the returned data to innerHTML.

However (unsurprisingly) I lose the draggable/droppable capability.  I've tried using destroy, create, enable etc but without success.  I've also put the instantiation (is that the right word?) into a separate function which is called at document ready and, again, when reloading the data - still doesn't work.

What would I need to do to make this work?

BTW the draggable and droppable elements each have their own unique id.

TIA

Doug

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to re-instate these elements is to create an additional hidden table that mirrors the table with the droppable elements.  When re-instating the saved state the re-instating process goes through each row of this table and updates the original draggable elements (each of which has a unique id) accordingly.